# PHP function returns array when result should not be an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP.  I have a function that should return a single record containing a single column, 1 or 0:

```
function is_pitcher($player_id)  {
  global $db;
  $query = 'SELECT IF (position = 1, 1, 0) AS is_pitcher FROM players WHERE player_id = :player_id';
  $statement = $db->prepare($query);
  $statement->bindValue(':player_id', $player_id);
  $statement->execute();
  $is_pitcher = $statement->fetchAll();
  $statement->closeCursor();
  return $is_pitcher;
```

On my control page, I have an `IF` statement that evaluates `$is_pitcher` for values 1 and 0:

```
if ($action == 'get_player') {
  $player_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'player_id');
  $is_pitcher = is_pitcher($player_id);
if ($is_pitcher == 1) {...
```

Testing the value with `echo $is_pitcher` shows that it's an array, and thus can't be evaluated this way.  I have tried the function with both `fetch()` and `fetchAll()` with the same result.

I can get the value of `$is_pitcher` with `echo $is_pitcher['is_pitcher']` but doing so on the control page breaks it.

Is there a way to write the function that does not return an array? Or, is there a way to evaluate the variable as an array?

ETA: In answer to a comment, here's the structure of the array:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'is_pitcher' => '0', 0 => '0', ), )
```

Comment: can you show us the structure of the array in `$is_pitcher`, use `var_export($is_pitcher);`

Comment: `fetchAll` always returns an array (array can be length of 1), try `$is_pitcher[0]`

Comment: You can reference `$is_pitcher[0]['is_pitcher']` - i.e. `if ($is_pitcher[0]['is_pitcher'] == 1) {...`

Comment: A simple var_dump or print_r would’ve saved a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

`PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows`
So, yes, it should be an array, even with one result.